# JSON-LD error in Structured Data Testing Tool: "Missing '}' or object member name"

Tags: json, json-ld

I am trying to fix the error in JSON-LD strings. However, when I run test on structured data testing tool, it shows

> **Uncategorized Errors**  Missing '}' or object member name.

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/","name":"SiteTitle","creator":{"@type":"Thing","name":"name of the Name","accountablePerson":{"@type":"Person","name":"person name",}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, your json is not valid. You have a comma and miss a key "}"

Here is your json fixed:

```
{
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"WebSite",
   "url":"https://www.example.com/",
   "name":"SiteTitle",
   "creator":{
      "@type":"Thing",
      "name":"name of the Name",
      "accountablePerson":{
         "@type":"Person",
         "name":"person name"
      }
   }
}
```